# How to use libipmitool library of ipmiTool?

Tags: ipmitool, ipmi

As given in the below link 
http://ipmiutil.sourceforge.net/docs/ipmisw-compare.htm
That there is a library API for IpmiTool called libipmitool. 
But I am not able to find any document/link/ or any user/programmer guide for IpmiTool's lib API. 
I can only find lib API for openIPMI and FreeIPMI. 
Could you please help in getting information on IpmiTool lib API ?

Thanks 
S sarath

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that such a library exist as it doesn't appear in any search results.

In any case, if your main purpose is to monitor the SDR repository I highly recommend on using [ipmimonitoring](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ipmimonitoring) or [libipmimonitoring](http://www.gnu.org/software/freeipmi/manpages/man3/libipmimonitoring.3.html) because it interpret sensor readings rather than just report them. The tool will output if sensors are in NOMINAL, WARNING, or CRITICAL states.

Answer (score 0):

I face a similar problem like sarath. After some research I was able to use OpenIPMI and its library. After the installation of OpenIPMI I was able to include the OpenIPMI Libs to my Sourcecode.

[Here](http://openipmi.sourceforge.net/IPMI.pdf) you find a manual to OpenIPMI. 
Chapter 2.3 give an overlook and a small description of the header files one can include. In Chapter 2.4 and 2.5 you find some sample source code to start with.

Additonal example sourcecode can be found [here](http://openipmi.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.0.2-2/dir_a68f95d36b8d11076918d4b3f478d7a9.html).

I will give it a try for my work with IPMI stuff.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.